# Unable to use pip and conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I installed python using anaconda. But an error happende this way.

ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\Users\FMV\anaconda3\Lib\collections\_*init*_.py)

I didn't change any of code which is directly downloaded from website. How to fix this error and be able to use pip command.

I set the path

C:\Users\FMV\anaconda3

C:\Users\FMV\anaconda3\Library\bin

C:\Users\FMV\anaconda3\Scripts

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without an understanding of your environment, and specifically how you have Anaconda installed.  In addition, please explain  when the reported error occurs.  Is this during installation of Anaconda, or later. Please edit your question to show equired information.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.